# Conversion of 2D array into a 1D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

we have 2-d array and I want to convert this array in 1D array. I am getting the output 3 times of single array. i want the the output of 1d array is 1 time.
I need the output in single array & sorting the elements.

```
package com.vidhu;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MatrixConvert 
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i,j,flag=0;
    int count=10;
    int ar[][]=new int[2][3];
    int arCopy[]=new int[6];

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
         for(j=0;j<3;j++)
         {
              ar[i][j]=count;
              count++;
         }
    }
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
         for(j=0;j<3;j++)
         {
              System.out.print(ar[i][j]);
              System.out.print(" ");
         }
         System.out.println(" ");
     }

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
         for(j=0;j<3;j++)
         {
              arCopy[flag]=ar[i][j];
              flag++;
         }
     }
    System.out.println(" ");
    for(i=0;i<arCopy.length;i++)
    {
         System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arCopy));
         Arrays.sort(arCopy);

         System.out.print(" ");
 }

 }
}
```

output:

```
10 11 12  
13 14 15  

[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go, I added the sorting you asked for,
this code resorts the array1D[] in that special order You mentioned:

```
package matrixConvertion;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class matrixConvertion {

        public static void main(String[] args)
            {

                int i,j=0;
                int count=10;
                int array2D[][]=new int[2][3];
                int array1D[]=new int[6];

                for(i=0;i<2;i++)
                {
                     for(j=0;j<3;j++)
                     {
                          array2D[i][j]=count;
                          count++;
                     }
                }

                for(i=0;i<2;i++)
                {
                     for(j=0;j<3;j++)
                     {
                          array1D[i+j+i*(array2D[0].length-1)] = array2D[i][j];                       
                     }
                }   
                System.out.println("1D array is:");
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1D));


                Arrays.sort(array1D);
                System.out.println("sorted 1D array is:");
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1D));
                int n=0, g=2;
                int[] reSorted=new int[array1D.length];
                for(int k=0; k<array1D.length; k++)
                {   
                      reSorted[k]=array1D[array1D.length-1-n];                    
                      n+=g;
                         if(n>=array1D.length)
                         {
                            n=array1D.length-1; g=-2; 
                         }
                }
                System.out.println("reSorted 1D array is:");
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reSorted));              


            }

}
```

Comment: thnx.. i want to one more thing... i want to arrange this array in like this form [15 13 11 10 12 14]. 15 is the highest value that is 1st position of the & then 14 is small from 15 that is last position oa the array.rest of arrange  like that in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your final statement is doing this:

```
 for(i=0;i<arCopy.length;i++) // for i= 0 i< array length (6))
{
     System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arCopy)); // print the full array
     Arrays.sort(arCopy);  // sort the array

     System.out.print(" ");
}
```

And there is a loop, you can change that doing only this:

```
Arrays.sort(arCopy);
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arCopy));
```

or

```
Arrays.sort(arCopy);
for(i=0;i<arCopy.length;i++) 
{
     System.out.print(arCopy[i] + " "); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arCopy))
```

Displays the whole array. You are displaying and sorting the array six times.

Answer (score 0):

Your final print statement is in a loop that will cycle 6 times. Remove the final for clause, and you will print it only once.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.toString() method will print all elements in the single dimension array. You no need this for loop.

Remove this code.

```
for(i=0;i<arCopy.length;i++)
{
      System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arCopy));
      Arrays.sort(arCopy);

      System.out.print(" ");
 }
```

and do like this

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arCopy));
 Arrays.sort(arCopy);
 System.out.println("After sorting");
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arCopy));
```